# Composer update not reflecting repository changes

Tags: php, composer-php

I have the follow `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "mjohnson/transit",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "A file uploader, validator, importer and transformer library.",
    "keywords": [
        "transit", "file", "uploader", "validator", "importer", "transformer", "transporter",
        "image", "audio", "video", "text", "application", "archive", "s3", "glacier"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://milesj.me/code/php/transit",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Miles Johnson",
            "homepage": "http://milesj.me"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.0.*"
    },
    "support": {
        "source": "https://github.com/milesj/php-transit"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "Transit": "src/" }
    }
}
```

when I run a `composer update` the source code is not updated to reflect current repository: `https://github.com/milesj/transit`

I tried to delete lock file whitout success. Tried `composer [update|install}`

For instance, my current (local) code:

`src/Transit/File.php`:

```
[...]
public function __construct($path) {
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        throw new IoException(sprintf('%s does not exist', $path));
    }

    $this->_path = $path;
}
[...]
```

current [repository code](https://github.com/milesj/transit/blob/master/src/Transit/File.php#L44):

```
[...]
public function __construct($path) {
    if (is_array($path)) {
        if (empty($path['tmp_name'])) {
            throw new IoException('Passing via array must use $_FILES data');
        }

        $this->_data = $path;
        $path = $path['tmp_name'];
    }

    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        throw new IoException(sprintf('%s does not exist', $path));
    }

    $this->_path = $path;

    // @version 1.3.2 Rename file to add ext if ext is missing
    if (!$this->ext()) {
        $this->rename();
    }

    // @version 1.4.0 Reset the cache
    $this->_cache = array();
}
[...]
```

Comment: Did you configure the `packagist hooks` in github ? If yes, when your composer.json is wrong, packagist will not update the composer package and you need to force the upload on the packagist website to see what is wrong.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant it is not mine repository. I am only a "consumer"..

Comment: Ok. Composer package (these stored over packagist) are updated each 5 min (if the package has been pushed less than 5 min ago, if you were in this case, it's normal you couldn't use it, and now it would be ok). Else, you should notify the developper that there is this problem.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant It is a 10 days old push. I already opened a support ticket.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant I have only composer for vendor. Should I have a composer file for my own project?

Comment: It's strange, https://packagist.org/packages/mjohnson/transit shows the commit is referenced by "0ba9084" and on https://github.com/milesj/transit it's the same (the other is reduced). It should work, move the vendor directory to vendor-save, and `composer update`

Comment: Yes you must have a composer.json at the root of your project, as in mine: https://github.com/crakouille/pegase-project/blob/master/composer.json  . Create your composer.json with the good `require` statements, and launch `php composer.phar update` at the root of your project

Comment: So, it seens that this is the problem. Composer which I am executing is updating self dependencies, not it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong `composer.json`. The one you mention is for the library named "mjohnson/transit" - if you are not developing this exact software, then this is wrong.

You should create a new composer.json file containing at least this line:

```
{ "require": { "mjohnson/transit" : "*" } }
```

Then run `composer install`.

I do not know what you did to get that `composer.json` file, but if you originally cloned that other repository, and now edit that file, things will break! Backup your code if any. Try to undo what you did wrong without undoing your own code.

Comment: Hey, I thought that each composer update dependencies and itself, so, I accessed my vendor folder and executed a `composer update` inside it.

Comment: No, you define one `composer.json` for YOUR project, and then install and update it. There is no need to update every library you used individually. In fact it is counter productive, because the dependencies of everything have to be evaluated in one go, not seperately.